Approximate the value of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n!^m}$.
I wish to understand the series
$$S_m:=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n!^m}$$
for $m\ge2$. Of course it would be ideal to have a simple exact form for it but I don't hope one exists, so my aim is to get a good approximation for it.
To start, one can easily notice $(S_m)_m$ is strictly decreasing and tends to $1$, so $1<S_m<S_1 = e-1$ for all $m\ge 2$.
With a little more effort one notices $n!^m > \sqrt2^{(m-1)n} n!$ for $n\ge 2$, therefore
$$S_m< 1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(\sqrt2^{1-m})^n}{n!} = e^{\sqrt2^{1-m}}-\sqrt2^{1-m}.$$
The next obvious thing to try is Stirling's approximation $n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n$, which gives us
$$S_m\approx \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}^m}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{mn}}{n^{m(n+1/2)}}$$
but this doesn't appear to be more manageable than the original series.
It's worth mentioning the elegant inequality
$$(mn)!\le e^{mn}(m!)^n (n!)^m.$$
but once again, this doesn't seem to produce a manageable series for bounding $S_m$.

This summand is very rapidly decreasing.  What do you not like about taking, say, the first 20 terms of the sum as the approximation, yielding an upper bound on the absolute error of about $10^{-19}$?

@EricTowers my interest in this series is not numerical, but analytical. Simply taking a partial sum is not very enlightening about its behavior and also kinda awkward to work with. I would much prefer to bound it with more simple functions.

Just taking two terms, we have $$1+2^{-m} \leq S_m \leq 1+2^{-m} + \left( \mathrm{e}-\frac{5}{2} \right)^m$$ (because $0 < S_m \leq (\mathrm{e}-1)^m$).

Perhaps the Question does not make it clear what features of $S_m$ you want to expose in your approximation.

@EricTowers you're approximation is actually great! I'm honestly not really sure how you derived it. Please, feel free to post it as an answer. I don't know how does it compare with the one I derived on the post, though.

The modified Bessel function $I_0(z)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z/2)^{2m}}{m!^2}$ so $S_2=I_0(2)$.

Let's define
$$  S_a^b(m) = \sum_{n=a}^b (n!)^{-m}  \text{.}  $$
We wish to study $S_m = S_1^\infty(m)$ for $m \geq 2$.
We should note this is sort of like the series for $\mathrm{e} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n!)^{-1}$.
The first term of $S_1^{\text{whatever}}(m)$ is $1$, the second term is $2^{-m}$ and subsequent terms are even smaller, so we should expect the first two terms to be the bulk of the sum.  Let's start with the relation for $\mathrm{e}$ (whose first three terms are $1$, $1$, and $1/2$), and see what we can get.  \begin{align*}
\mathrm{e} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n!)^{-1}  \\
    &= 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=3}^\infty (n!)^{-1}
\end{align*}
so
$$  \mathrm{e}-\frac{5}{2} = \sum_{n=3}^\infty (n!)^{-1} = S_3^\infty(1)  \text{.}  $$
For $n \geq 1$ and $m \geq 1$,
$$  n! \leq n!^{m}  $$
so \begin{align*}
n!^{-1} &\geq n!^{-m}  \\
\sum_{n=3}^\infty n!^{-1} &\geq \sum_{n=3}^\infty n!^{-m} 
\end{align*}
If we (pretend $m$ is an integer and use the multinomial formula on partial sums to) expand $\left(\sum_{n=3}^\infty n!^{-1}\right)^{m} = \left( S_3^\infty(1) \right)^m$, every term in $\sum_{n=3}^\infty n!^{-m}$ appears together with many additional positive terms, so
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{n=3}^\infty n!^{-1} \right)^m &\geq \sum_{n=3}^\infty n!^{-m}  \\
\left( \mathrm{e} - \frac{5}{2} \right)^{m} &\geq S_3^\infty(m)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Let's pop the first two terms out of our series for $S_m$.  Since all the terms are positive, these are a lower bound for the series.  \begin{align*}
1 + 2^{-m} &\leq S_1^\infty(m)  \\
    &= 1 + 2^{-m} + S_3^\infty(m)  \\
    &\leq 1 + 2^{-m} + \left( \mathrm{e} - \frac{5}{2} \right)^{m}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
recreating the estimate that appears in comments to the Question.  Since $1/5 \leq \mathrm{e}-5/2 \leq 1/4$, the width of the estimation interval decreases fairly quickly as $m$ increases (although $S_m$ is always closer to the lower bound than to the upper).
If we repeat all the above with one more term, we obtain
$$  1 + 2^{-m} + 6^{-m} \leq S_1^\infty(m) \leq 1 + 2^{-m} + 6^{-m} + \left(\mathrm{e} - \frac{8}{3}\right)^m  \text{.}  $$
Since $1/20 \leq \mathrm{e}-8/3 \leq 1/19$, the width of the estimation interval decreases very quickly as $m$ increases (although $S_m$ is always closer to the lower bound than to the upper).

If you happen to have a library for generalized hypergeometric functions, then for $m \in \Bbb{Z}$, $m \geq 2$,
$$  S_m = -1 + {}_0 F_{m-1}\left( ; \underbrace{1,1,1,\dots,1}_{\text{$m-1$ times}} ; 1\right)  \text{.}  $$
(This is not a deep observation.  The hypergeometric series already has an $n!$ in the denominator and each "lower" $1$ gives a factor of $\frac{\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n!}$, so there are a total of $m$ "$n!$"s multiplied together in the denominator.  With $z = 1$, the powers of $z$ vanish, leaving $S_m$.)

It might make more sense to look at $\ln S_m$ since $S_m$ is barely greater than $1$ once $m$ is more than, say, ten.  Just messing around with fits over $m \in [10,100]$, it looks like
$$  \ln S_m \approx \mathrm{e}^{-0.000188621369 - 0.693144609 m}  \text{.} $$
I wouldn't use that for $m < 20$.  For $m = 20$, the error is a little less than $10^{-9}$ for $\ln S_m$ and decreases very rapidly as $m$ increases.  We can exponentiate again and the numbers are so near $1$ that the error is essentially unchanged at $m = 20$.  That is, with error a little less than $10^{-9}$ at $m = 20$ and dwindling rapidly as $m$ increases,
$$  S_m \approx \exp( \exp( -0.000188621369 - 0.693144609 m ))  \text{.}  $$
(BTW: I haven't verified that the coefficient of $m$ is not $\ln 2$ as the fitting interval $\rightarrow [2,\infty)$.  If it is, then we are once again being told that the sum is essentially $1 + 2^{-m}$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$.)

When $m = 2$, we get the modified Bessel function of the first kind. Have a look here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html. In particular, $S_2 = I_0(2) - 1$.

This is not helpful

@AlmaArjuna But, it’s an idea.

I did it as a comment (before I saw this) so less chance of reputation damage. Anyway, I upvoted you.

I believe the answer is $$F\left(m+1\right)\ =\ \frac{1+F\left(m\right)}{2}$$
for a very close approximation.
EDIT: The function $1+2^{-m}$ obeys this equality, which matches up with the other responder Eric Towers suspicions about it.
My strategy was shunting 1/k! into a different series, that converges; then, hoping it can be reversed afterwards.
First tweak the definition of F(m) to fix a problem later:
$$F\left(m\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{m}}=1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{m}}$$
Summate with respect to m, then pull the new m-index summation into the original k-index sum, and evaluate:
$$\sum_{m=2}^{x}F\left(m\right)\ =\ \left(x-1\right)+\sum_{m=2}^{x}\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{m}}\right)$$
$$\sum_{m=2}^{x}F\left(m\right)\ =\left(x-1\right)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)}\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{x}}}{1-\frac{1}{k!}}\right)-\frac{1}{k!}\right)$$
What remains are some series which converge, but also, something extremely close to the original series:
$$\sum_{m=2}^{x}F\left(m\right)=\left(x-1\right)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k!-1}\right)-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{x}\cdot\left(k!-1\right)}-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$$
$$\sum_{m=2}^{x}F\left(m\right)\ =\ \left(x-1\right)+1.2535-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{m}\cdot\left(k!-1\right)}-0.71828$$
I'll call these constants W, and eliminate (x-1) by subtracting the first term of F(m), which leaves:
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{m=2}^{x}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{m}}\right)\ \ =W-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{\left(x\right)}\left(k!-1\right)}$$
Which becomes a function of x that converges to constant:
$$W=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{\left(x\right)}\left(k!-1\right)}+\sum_{m=2}^{x}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{m}}\right)$$
I believed I was stuck here, but actually, for reasons unknown, the following convergence immediately happens after x=1:* see below to edit 2
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{\left(x-1\right)}\left(k!-1\right)}\ =\ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{x}}$$
And therefore we thus obtain:
$$W=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{\left(x+1\right)}}+\sum_{m=2}^{x+1}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{m}}\right)$$
Then define G(m)
$$G\left(m\right)=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{m}}\ =\ F\left(m\right)-1$$
$$W=G\left(x+1\right)+\sum_{m=2}^{x+1}G\left(m\right)$$
Equating two converging series for x and x+1 leads to the final clue:
$$G\left(x+1\right)+\sum_{m=2}^{x+1}G\left(m\right)\ =G\left(x\right)+\sum_{m=2}^{x}G\left(m\right)$$
$$2\cdot G\left(x+1\right)\ =G\left(x\right)$$
$$2\left(F\left(x+1\right)-1\ \right)=\ F\left(x\right)-1$$
$$F\left(x+1\right)\ =\ \frac{\left(F\left(x\right)-1\right)}{2}+1\ $$
And thus:
$$F\left(x+1\right)\ =\ \frac{F\left(x\right)+1}{2}$$
EDIT 2: * If that particular series is geniunely evaluated instead of approximated for x over 1, it's really
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{\left(x-1\right)}\left(k!-1\right)}\ =\sum_{b=x}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(k!\right)^{b}}\right)$$
Which for whatever it's worth, proves the following about G(m), which gives a hint to F(m) :
$$W=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}G\left(m\right)\ =\ 0.535216927241$$

@YvesDaoust Yeah, a real bummer I didn't notice.
